# Capybara/Selenium - Allow location detection

Tags: selenium, geolocation, selenium-webdriver, capybara, saucelabs

Is there a way to tell capybara/selenium to allow the detection of the current physical location of the user?

Or is there something like a crossbrowser workaround to click on the "Allow" button?

[image]

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16292634/2504101 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write a Selenium mouse Action  that would start at a location on the page and then move a certain number of X and Y pixels and then click on the Allow button.   The location where the mouse movement starts needs to be on the actual webpage though.

If you find that the mouse pointer wont go outside of the window frame, then you can use [Sikuli](https://github.com/andreanastacio/rukuli) to do it but if you do that, your test wont work through a Selenium Grid.

Comment: Well I had the same idea first too, but each browser has a different popup for that.

Comment: Ok, you didn't say you were concerned with that in your question.  You will have to wait for Mozilla Marionette to be adopted by all browsers then.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you next variant. If some HTTP requests is sent after user presses 'Allow' button then you can send such request from your script using something like [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) but for Ruby.  Probably this one https://rubygems.org/gems/httpclient

Comment: It's a browser feature and AFAIK no HTTP requests are sent.