# How to select a button on popup using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

When the user navigates to the page, a small popup window appears asking the user to "Share Location" like in the screen shot below. 
[image]

So I wonder how can I use Protractor to simulate the user's click on the "Share Location" button (apparently, `element(by.buttonText("Share Location")).click();` doesn't work).

Also the browser in this screenshot is Firefox and as different browser may  have different messages/styles how can I then tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this button is not in the DOM and you *cannot control it with protractor/selenium*. You need to avoid it being opened in the first place and let the browser know how to automatically respond.

Applying the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238478/771848) (not tested):

```
browser.executeScript("navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success) { success({coords: {latitude: 50.455755, longitude: 30.511565}}); }");
```

You can also solve it by setting the `geo.prompt.testing` and `geo.prompt.testing.allow` to `true` in the [FirefoxProfile preferences](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/blob/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile/conf.js). Sample protractor config with a `makeFirefoxProfile()` helper function:

```
var q = require("q");
var FirefoxProfile = require("firefox-profile");

var makeFirefoxProfile = function(preferenceMap, specs) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    for (var key in preferenceMap) {
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
    }

    firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        var capabilities = {
            firefox_profile: encodedProfile,
            specs: specs
        };

        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

exports.config = {
    getMultiCapabilities: function() {
        return q.all([
            makeFirefoxProfile(
                {"geo.prompt.testing": true, "geo.prompt.testing.allow": true},
                ["specs/*.spec.js"]
            )
        ]);
    },

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't get `require("q")`. Did you use requirejs or something? As when running the protractor conf, it throws "Error: Cannot find module 'q'"

Comment: I also tried the "browser.executeScript" solution but it still does not work.