# how to download a file given a link using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, select

I have been downloading a file for stock market data using urllib, which was working fine, but recently that has been blocked from locations out of country, and I am currently outside. :( hence, I am thinking of selenium using python using firefox where I can do geo spoofing.
l have the link, can we download using selenium just by link or do I must have clickable buttons to proceed?

thanks a lot,
sudip

Comment: It depends on the download link -- sometimes, you need to be authenticated when you trigger a download, which works fine in the browser scenario with clickable buttons. But making a request to the download URL might not work without any authentication in place. It depends on your website.

Comment: there's no authentication, the file is there(end of day data), I have the link, its available only if request arises from India, no authentication stuff...thanks

Comment: Chrome should do it by default... just click the link to the file. (Going direct to the file's URL will break the DOM) Firefox will prompt by default.  These options are configurable.  Also remember not to close the driver before the download completes.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. Open firefox with geospoof and you can click the link to download. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40237170/4300192