# handle pop up in Selenium in firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am making a tinder auto swipe using Selenium.
I am using a firefox browser to run the script and the script is written in python.
I want to handle pop up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xz9p.png) but unable to handle it.
I have use driver.switch_to.alert.accept() but its returning exception' raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: '

Comment: [Always Allow Geolocation in Firefox using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144965/13149512)

Comment: You can check the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767551/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-browser-using-selenium-webdriver) and try possible solutions.

Comment: thanks but i was looking for python code and in the link its written in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the preference in the options before opening the page. 
Try this:

```
geo_location = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
geo_location.set_preference('geo.prompt.testing', True)
geo_location.set_preference('geo.prompt.testing.allow', True)
# This will mock a certain location:
geo_location.set_preference('geo.provider.network.url',
    'data:application/json,{"location": {"lat": 10.0, "lng": 10.0}, "accuracy": 100.0}')

# Pass options into the profile and open your page
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=geo_location)
driver.get('https://tinder.com/app/recs')
```

I hope this helps, it worked for me. Good luck!